# Finding minimum value across multiple python lists and printing which list it came from

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have multiple lists and I'd like to perform three operations to them. The first, is to find the lowest value, element wise, through each list.

Then I'd like to print out the respective list that houses that element

Then I'd like to perform basic mathematical operations to the counts

```
john = [5, 7, 6, 4, 7, 5, 4, 4, 4]
dylan = [4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5]
nate = [5, 4, 7, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4]
curt = [4, 6, 8, 4, 6, 3, 5, 4, 4]

stacked_arrays = np.dstack((john, dylan, nate, curt))
min_of_stack = stacked_arrays.min(2)
print min_of_stack

[[4 4 3 4 5 3 4 4 4]]
```

So I am at the point where I know which is the value that is the min amongst the 4 lists, but I don't know how to figure out which min is the least. In the event that there are multiple lists where the least value is housed, then I'd like to not print anything.

Any ideas or thoughts to a better way to approach this? Thanks

Comment: `argmin` may help

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to use numpy you could just use the built-in `min(list)` function:

```
john = [5, 7, 6, 4, 7, 5, 4, 4, 4]
dylan = [4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5]
nate = [5, 4, 7, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4]
curt = [4, 6, 8, 4, 6, 3, 5, 4, 4]
people = [john, dylan, nate, curt]

min = 1000
for i in people:
    if min(i) < min:
        min = min(i)
```